# Highlight the products added in the cart

Tags: magento2, addtocart, knockoutjs

I am trying to make functionality on the category page in which the product which is in the cart shows a right mark beside the product name. I am able to achieve it for the norma add to cart but I am stuck with the ajax add to cart. Similarly, the right mark should be removed when the item is no longer in the cart.